# BSOD during git push corrupt local branch

Tags: git, corruption

Lucky for me, win10 decided to BSOD me exactly when i was pushing my local branch. After reboot, git could not keep track of my repo.

`git status` returned: `fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.`.

I checked this `.git/HEAD` pointed to `refs/heads/<my-branch>`. I opened that file and it contains gibberish, whilst `refs/heads/master` contains a hash of some sort.

Is there any way to repair my local repo?

Comment: I found the previous commit hash in `logs/heads/<branch>` and changed HEAD to point to it, luckly i only had a small typo commit after it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting HEAD using `git update-ref`:

```
git update-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
```

Alternatively, you can also simply put the following content inside the `.git/HEAD` file:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```